# Hide next div which matches the the condition using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm able to wrap the text inside a div and hide them. In addition to that I need to hide the next div also. But, it doesn't work. Did I miss anything?

### Here is my html

```
<small>
    Size: M<div class="item-devider"></div> 
    checkbox_test: Yes<div class="item-devider"></div>
    I don't mind about color: No<div class="item-devider"></div> 
    test: No<div class="item-devider"></div> 
    test_group: select1<div class="item-devider"></div>
</small>
```

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var texts = $('#sample small').contents().filter(function(){
        return $(this).text().indexOf(': No') > -1;     
    }).wrap('<div style="display:none"/>').next().find('div').attr('display:none');

});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/1136/

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is `.attr('display:none')`?

Comment: Sorry....that should be .css(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the next sibling of parent `div` that you wrap around your text instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var texts = $('#sample small').contents().filter(function(){
        return $(this).text().indexOf(': No') > -1;     
    }).wrap('<div style="display:none"/>').parent().next().hide();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/1141/)**